# Windows phone 8, listbox, is it possible to scroll to end auto?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Listbox, which is binded to an observable collection. I want this listbox to scroll to end when an element is added into observablecollection.

I thought to add a listener to my observable collection, but I use same page for more than one session. So if it keeps a listener, after about 1000 open/close, page is just really slow.

The application is using SignalR and is meant to be alive for a year without problems.

I can provide sample code, but I don’t think it can help a problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you update the observable collection and refresh the listbox, you might try to set the `selectedindex` on the listbox to the `count-1`, and `focus` on the listbox (`listbox.Focus()`)

Comment: Sorry, no, this doesn’t respond question at all… To do this I MUST put a listener on my observable collection. If I do so, listener stays and will be reapplied if user close and reopen the page. This is not an answer, I’ve already seen this solution. I want a listener on listbox, or a solution to remove listener when user leave a page.

Comment: You can unsubscribe in the OnNavigatedFrom event and subscribe in the Loaded event. BTW, the event is probably called scrollintoview in the WP8, not focus